# Jenkins Slaves don´t terminate ant processes in case of timeout errors

Tags: java, ant, jenkins

We have got a Jenkins Master with several slaves. The slaves are started via JNLP. The jobs are executed using ant.

When the job executed by a slave times out, the ant-process is not terminated. Timeouts occure because of endless Unit-Tests, OutOfMemoryErrors etc.

The next time the job starts, Jenkins tries to clean the workspace before executing the job. It fails, because of a java.nio.file.FileSystemException.

The exception is caused by the ant-process still running on the slave. It has got handles on the files.

> **My Time-out configuration:**
>
> **Time-out strategy:** absolute
>
> **Timeout minutes:** 3
>
> **Time-out variable:** 660
>
> **Time-out actions:** Default (abort the build)

My workaround solution is to terminate the ant-processes manually whenever a job timed out on the slave.

How can I prevent this problem? How can I make sure the ant-processes executed on the slave machines are terminated in case of Job-Timeouts?

Comment: Hello, I guess you have set the "Abort the build if its stuck" setting and set the minutes after which it should abort. Since it isn't really stuck I believe this doesn't help anyway. Select "absolute" and it aborts when time has run out.

Comment: You can even select likely stuck, then it should abort after the given time anyway, you have to the settings to find an appropriate one.

Comment: Thank you, Charles. I updated the question with the time-out configuration.